# YouTube API: Dashboard vs API Console

Tags: youtube.net-api

I'm implementing server-side interactions with YouTube and I'm a bit lost with the kind of Product/App you need to create in order to publish videos via the API for example.

Looking at the [OAuth2 doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2), it says that I need to register my app with the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) (looks good so far, very similar to creating a Facebook App).
But then, I looked at the Google [.NET library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet#Authentication) and here it says that a Product needs to be registered in the [YouTube dashboard](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard)... Not sure to understand how these are complementary. If anyone has a synthetic explanation (which I didn't found in the docs), I would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I believe:

1. The YouTube Dashboard was originally setup prior to the announcement of YouTube API v3, which is yet to be released. You use the Dashboard to register your application and get a YT Dev Key. You can also use the Dashboard for some extremely low level application statistics.
2. The API Console is Google's attempt to form one administrative console for ALL of their APIs. Since Google is transistioning to oAuth 2 authorization, you will need to use the API console as well in order to apply for a clientID, redirectURI, and clientSecret if you want to authorize with oAuth 2.

At this time, if you do not want to use oAuth2 you do not need access to the API Console. However, know that in February of next year YouTube is going to kill all other forms of authorization (sub, clientLogin, oAuth1).

So to try and simplify things:
Use the API Console to get your oAuth2 in order
Use the YT Dashboard to get a YT Dev Key

In the future, when Google goes lives with YouTube API v3, you will probably want to switch to a new Dev Key from the API Console and leave the Dashboard all together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's roughly what I understood... I was (and still am) wondering why the process of setting up a YT app with OAuth2 is so complicated and inconsistent!